# Association rules algorithm

Tags: algorithm, associations, data-mining, rules

I am new to data mining. I want to mine multi-dimensional and ordinal association rules from my data set e.g.

```
if (income => 100) ^ (priority=>1) ^ (skill=>technician ) then (approve=>prove)
```

What I have learned  is that 
categorical =   for skills e.g. technician, plumber or any textual data
quantitative = numeric for date, balance

So major then is which association rule algorithm should be used? Mostly algorithm are quantitative or categorical is there any combined?

Comment: Treat `(skill=>technician)` as a boolean function that gives you 1 or 0, then it's now a quantitative evaluation

Comment: is there any algorithm for association rules for quantitative and categorical data ?

Comment: My comment above is the usual rule used, treat categorical data as a boolean match or not match when evaluating -- this is oftentimes stored in matrix form for quick querying across different categories/elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding the concept of association rule mining on its own.
Your quantitative data cannot be used as such in association rule mining (as I understood your question). At least, you cannot 'tune' the quantity to fit your needs because everything in association rule mining is either items (quantitative or qualitative) and transactions so that you can define the rules that relate the items between each other. Therefore, the quantities become 'fixed' items.

Note what is association rule mining: given a set of binary attributes (items) and set of transactions, each containing a subset of items, you define a set of rules, which are implications: X -> Y (with X and Y being subsets of the set of items, and disjunct as well).

You can interpret it (or model) the implication of a rule as an if, but that is just syntactic sugar. There are not quantitative or qualitative as we know them in association rule mining. Just, items that belong to a set and the relationships (implications/rules) that we define between them.